# Memory not freed up after deleting linked list's last node

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures, linked-list, delete-operator

I coded the following. Insert, delete at beginning, insert at beginning and end are all working fine. The memory marked in bold is not freed up. Should **`cout<<temp`** give an error? Please comment on the correctness of this code.

```
void del(node** head)
{
    node* temp = (*head)->next;
    node* prev = *head;
    while(temp ->next!= NULL)
    {
        prev = temp;
        temp = temp -> next;
    }
    cout<<endl<<temp;
    cout<<endl<<prev;

    //delete prev ->next;
    prev -> next = 0;

    delete temp;
    cout<<endl<<"temp after free"<<temp;
    cout<<endl<<prev;
}
void main()
{
    node* head = NULL;  
int x = 5;
head = insert(head,x);
insert(head,6);
insert(head,7);
insert(head,8);
print(head);
del(&head);
print(head);
getch();    }
```

Output:

```
Empty List
|5| at 00673BF0
-------------------
|6| at 00673C30
-------------------
|7| at 00673FB8
-------------------
|8| at 00673FF8
-------------------

00673FF8
00673FB8
temp after free00673FF8
00673FB8

|5| at 00673BF0
-------------------
|6| at 00673C30
-------------------
|7| at 00673FB8
-------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`delete` does not set the value of the pointer to NULL, but the memory pointed to is no longer valid (does not contain a live `node`)

This means that `cout << temp` will print the value of the pointer it still has (and was the address of the node before the `delete`), but dereferencing `temp` (e.g. `*temp` or `temp->next`) is undefined behavior

*Note*: nowehere in `del` do you modify the pointer pointed to by `head`, so you either don't need the double indirection (`node**`) or you should assign the new head to `*head`.

Comment: delete temp;
temp ->d = 20;
cout<<endl<<"temp after free"<<temp ->d;
gave 20. Will you treat this as memory leak?

Comment: @Rohan - cannot tell for sure without seeing other parts of the code, but you should also account for the edge cases when `*head` or `(*head)->next` is `NULL`, otherwise you might get a crash (dependeing on your usage of `del()`)

Comment: `delete temp; temp->d=20;` is undefined behavior (you are accessing an object that is no longer valid after the `delete`)

Comment: Attila: you are right. I have deliberately omitted boundary line case as I wanted to post a code for memory leak purpose only :) Still thanks and appreciate you pointed that out :). Well yes, the code is now behaving in an undefined way after i tried to reference the deleted temp->d . Solves my query.

Answer (score 1):

As Attila already pointed out it's undefined behavior to dereference a pointer after deleting it. To prevent accidentally doing that it's good practice to assign `NULL` to the pointer directly after the `delete`. Dereferencing a NULL pointer immediately causes an error pointing you to the right cause.

Answer (score 0):

In the code its good to free the temp node first. Then assign the prev->next to NULL. So that it will be very easy to understand that temp node is not available, thats way making prev->next NULL.